# How to make one of two column reach the end of the viewport horizontally

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
max-width: 1170px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.row::after {
    display: block;;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
}

.col {
    float: left;
}

.col-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

.content {
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;

    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col col-6">
            <div class="content">Half of container width</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-6">
            <div class="content green">The remaining part of the viewport 
horizontally
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to achieve this effect where the first col-6 spans the first 50% of the container's width , and the second col-6 spans from 50% of the containers width to the end of the viewport. I'd like to put an image there, if it matters ( if absolute positioning must be used ).
Hopefully this is descriptive enough

Comment: Well changing the width of the column itself won’t work, then the float construct will break apart. But specifying a width > 100% for the content element inside seems to work fine, then the overflow is just shown outside of the column bounds. So I guess you should be able to calculate the necessary width dynamically, similar to the approach used here, https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/ (there the method is used with margins, but you can apply the principle to width as well.)

Comment: just give your cols a min height off 100 vh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something with viewport units:

[updated codepen](https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/WdLENW)

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row::after {
  display: block;
  ;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}

.col {
  float: left;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.content {
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px
}

.half-vw .content {
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col col-6">
        <div class="content">Half of container width</div>
      </div>

      <div class="col col-6 half-vw">
        <div class="content">The remaining part of the viewport horizontally
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial to do with Flexbox.

Use `flex-basis : 50%` on the first child,

then `flex-grow : 1` on the second child (Meaning, "Take whatever space is left").

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
}
.row .first {
  background:green;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
.row .second {
  background: lightblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="first">First half</div>
  <div class="second">Remaining space</div>
</div>
```